# Have you ever entered Singapore using a different passport or name?

Tags: visas, passports, singapore

I change my nationality one year ago and my name is spelled differently in my new passport. I traveled to Singapore seven years ago with my Indonesian passport. It was spelled Nura and now is spelled Norah.

They have a question in the visa application "Have you ever entered Singapore using a different passport or name?"

Should I mark it as Yes or No?

Comment: The answer seems to be so obviously "Yes" that I must be missing something. Why are you unsure about what to answer?

Comment: You say you've changed nationality, so surely you must have a different passport?

Comment: Is anyone else waiting for the OP to change her username to Nura?

Comment: @Norah Changing your name's spelling legally is the same thing as changing your name.

Comment: Please don't delete the parts of your question that contain the information we need to answer it.

Comment: Related : https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123079/what-happens-if-i-indicate-on-my-singapore-arrival-card-that-i-have-entered-unde

Comment: Is there some ambiguity in the question that escapes me?

Comment: Just to add to what @only_pro said - it's worth nothing that this can often be a cultural difference. In some cultures, they can happily change the spelling of a name and consider it a mere preference - while still regarding it as essentially the same name. However in other cultures (including the West, using the Roman alphabet), words and names are intrinsically linked to their spellings. If you change just one letter, it is a **different name** - even if it sounds very similar.

Answer (score 39):

**You should answer Yes.**

Even if you hadn't spelled your name differently, because you used a different passport you would have to answer 'yes'. You should explain the circumstances fully.

Even if the name change was the only issue it would be better to answer 'yes'. The authorities are likely to look at the issue and treat it as a trivial matter. However if you don't tell them they may think you have something to hide, and technically you would have lied on an official form.

It is almost always better to put information on an official form if you are in doubt.

And to an organization that largely deals with written records, a change of spelling will be considered a change of name.

Answer (score 1):

You have two reasons to answer yes, different country's passport and different spelling. It should be obvious ..

Answer Yes, and put down your former citizenship, and former name. Since you were Indonesian, you were, I suppose, born there, and your birthplace will be enough for ICA officers to suspect you were, at some point, Indonesian. No mention of that fact would create issues: Singaporeans are very procedural.

Note: I suppose this is not for the visa, but the electronic arrival card - I filled it a couple of days ago and remember seeing this question.

Answer (score -4):

I would really **not** recommend lying to the authorities, especially in foreign countries, especially in Singapore where the death penalty is still a thing. Just mark Yes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I understood that Norah did not lie. It was a wrong info in a legal document.

Comment: There is no suggestion in the question that the asker wishes to wage war against Singapore, commit treason there, commit piracy or mutiny, murder anyone or commit genocide, kidnap anyone, help a minor or insane person commit suicide, commit perjury that causes an innocent person to be executed, get sent to jail for life and then attempt to murder somebody, commit firearms offences, or possess firearms, ammunition or explosives in a designated security area, so the death penalty really isn't on the cards. And I think they're just confused about what the question means, not trying to lie.

Comment: I'm just saying that within a country where the death penalty is still a thing probably other penalties are way more severe and lying to the authorities about your passport/visa would result in banning you from entering the country and probably some big fine. I do not understand the downvotes on my answer, to be honest - do you not agree lying to the authorities is a bad idea? Even if not intentional.

Comment: Also, the death penalty is applied for people who attempt to smuggle illegal drugs into the country. So your list is not complete. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: "And I think they're just confused about what the question means, not trying to lie." - intention is irrelevant when you lie